# Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch MS Access VBA Dlookup

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to get count of a matching data with `YES` in the table but experiencing

> Type mismatch

and unable to trace where I am missing. 
Someone please assist me.

[image]

```
Dim val As String
Dim srn As String
Dim qtrcount As Variant
Dim Qtrsrv As String

srn = Nz(Me.Service_Registration_Number.Value, 0)
val = Nz(DLookup("QTR_Service", "Service_MasterData", "[Service_Registration_Number] = '" & srn & "'"), 0)
If val = "YES" Then
**qtrcount = DCount("QTR_Service", "Service_MasterData", "[Service_Registration_Number]='" & srn & "'" And "QTR_Service ='" & val & "'")**
End If
```

`qtrcount` result should be 3

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the concatenation of the where part of `DCount`. It should read:

```
    qtrCount = DCount("QTR_Service", "Service_MasterData", "[Service_Registration_Number]='" & srn & "' And QTR_Service ='" & val & "'")
```

As an aside, if you have already determined that `val="YES"` it may be better to use YES in the where clause rather than concatenating `val`:

```
qtrCount = DCount("QTR_Service", "Service_MasterData", "[Service_Registration_Number]='" & srn & "' And QTR_Service ='YES'")
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you lot to assist ... superb . keep it up

Comment: @Amitjha: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.